# Set C# Button Style to another Button when hovered / clicked / unhovered

Tags: c#, winforms, button

How would I make two buttons appear the same when one is hovered over?

Picture of the buttons I want to be shown are here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4P6B.png

[image]

How would I make the button with the green image in the center appear as the same style (colors, borders, etc...) when the `Sign On` one has been hovered over / clicked?

I'm using Windows Forms.

Comment: are you using Windows Forms or WPF/Silverlight?

Comment: Windows Form is the technology as you can see by the picture above.

Comment: That picture doesn't convey the technology used at all, to be frank.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using event handlers on mouse over/out, but frankly the right choice is to make a usercontrol containing both buttons and use that instead of the two...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add handler for [MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx) event on your "sign on" button - all you have to do in this very handler then, is changing second button's styles (implementing [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) might be useful too - to revert second button to it's original style).

Code sample:

```
this.ButtonSignOn.MouseEnter += this.ChangeOtherButton;
this.ButtonSingOn.MouseLeave += this.RevertOtherButtonChanges;

// later on
private void ChangeOtherButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OtherButton.ForeColor = Colors.Red;
    this.OtherButton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    // more styling ...
}

// mostly same stuff when reverting changes
```

You could refactor those 2 handlers into one, and simply passing colors, fonts and other styles as you go... but this should be enough anyways.